# unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup

Tags: c++, templates, visual-c++, namespaces

I have been getting this error: 'unresolved external symbol *main referenced in function _*_tmainCRTStartup' when I attempt to compile my c++ console application. I have done some searching and all I could find was changing my 'linker' from windows to console or vice versa. This didn't work, I even tried creating a new console application.

I am unsure as to what is causing this, is it possible that `template <typename T>` is causing confusion as it appears in both files? Any help here would be much appreciated.

Code Below:

Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "tools.h"
using namespace tools;

template <typename T>
int main()
{
T input1;
T input2;

std::cout << "Enter in 1st number: " << endl;
std::cin >> input1;
std::cout << "Enter in 2nd number: " << endl;
std::cin >> input2;
std::cout << "num1 - num2 = [" << numberDifference(input1, input2) << "]" << endl;
getchar();
getchar();

return 0;
}
```

Tools.h:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace tools
{
template <typename T>
T numberDifference(T num1, T num2)
{
    if(num1 > num2)
        return num1 - num2;
    else
        return num2 - num1;
}
};
```

Comment: What the heck are you trying to do?

Comment: If 2 int's are entered it works out the difference between the two numbers, if its floats, same thing. If its longs then same again. That sort of concept.

Comment: Ah, that sounds like a different question. You should edit the question to make it about how to do that, not how to fix your solution, because your solution isn't going to work.

Comment: @Collin what if the user enters floating point numbers?

Comment: @ R. Martinho, Nick explained to me that I was templating the main function. I was attempting to "shortcut" having to parse the input. I need to not be lazy, lesson learned!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Remove the `template` definition for your `main` function.

Or at least call it from a proper `main` function.

e.g.

```
template< typename T >
int templated_main( int c, char** argv )
{
    // What was in your original main function....

}

int main( int c, char** argv )
{
    return templated_main<int>( c, argv );
}
```

Comment: It needs to be there otherwise I get 'undeclared Identifier' for every reference to T.

Comment: Well, yeah, T needs to be defined. How were you going to call your templated main?

Comment: Im not trying to make 'main' a template... I didnt know it did that :S

Comment: I get the same error with 'return main<int>( c, argv );' there.

Comment: And do you still have your templated main?

Comment: I guess what I have done is not realise how templates work. What I was trying to do was create a dynamic variable (like how I used the template with my function in tools) so I can pass in whatever (float, int, long, double ..)

Comment: Yeah, you can't really mess around with the `main` function otherwise the linker won't know how to start your application.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11376/discussion-between-flyphe-and-nick)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `template <typename T>` before main. That will make `main` a template function.

And change `T input1; T input2;` to some specific type, like `int` or `float`.